# Data Validation - List Combination With EXACT Formula

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Workbook with some Data Validations. Column D has the following List Validation ='Data Validation'!A1:A2

I need this to also include EXACT. Any time I try to use a custom formula to include EXACT it loses the list functionality. I can do one or the other but not the two together.

My data validation list contains 'Email'and 'Post'.
However I can input email into D2 and I don't get a validation error.

Column Name:
Member Contact Preference

D2 Value:
email

Comment: please mock up some data and expected results.

Comment: My permissions won't allow me to upload an image. I'll update with more info

Comment: Data Validation is not set up to do that.  I think you will need vba in a worksheet change event to capture the change and do a second check.

Comment: Hmmmmm, is it possible to apply dual validations? So one layer which checks the sheet and the second to check the exact match. I'm actually using this in conjunction with an RPA tool so can develop around the problem, but for future reference this would be useful I think.

Comment: no, only one validation rule per cell.